# How can I animate a series of png files in ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, png, animation

I have a folder `frames` of alphabetically ordered .png files. I'm trying to animate them somehow from the command line. Is there a quick command to make a movie from these files? I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have Image Magick installed:

```
convert -delay 20 -loop 0 frames/*.png animation.gif
```

[source](http://www.tjhsst.edu/~dhyatt/supercomp/n401a.html)